# preg_replace replaces url with hyperlink between [link] and [/link] but link can't cotain ? or ()

Tags: php, preg-replace

My code:

```
preg_match_all('(\[(link)\](.*?)\[/(link)\])', $message, $matches);
$matches = $matches[2];
foreach($matches as $match){
  //CHECK LINK AND VERIFY
  $message = preg_replace('(\[(link)\]('.$match.')\[/(link)\])', '<a href="'.$match.'" target="_blank">'.$match.'</a>', $message);
}
```

As you can see here https://mcskripts.dk/forum/id/286
The script works, but it can't replace links containing () or ?

Anyway i can fix that?

Sry, if i make a repost, just don't know if i can comment on old posts, and get a response.

Comment: You must add delimiters to your regex

Comment: Maybe you should use `preg_replace_callback()` to replace substring find by the regex : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: @Toto I think the `(` and `)` are the delimiters here. And that might cause a problem. Mikkel, try `'~\[link](.*?)\[/link]~'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes, but with that there is no group #2. It's simpler to add delimiers.

Comment: @Toto I did not notice there are two regex functions used :) What a waste of computing power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a single preg_replace:

```
$message = preg_replace('~\[link\](.+?)\[/link\]~', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $message);
```

If you want to validate the links before replace, use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$message = preg_replace_callback(
            '~\[link\](.+?)\[/link\]~', 
            function($match) {
                # call your function to validate the link
                if (validate_link($match[1])) {
                    return '<a href="'.$match[1].'" target="_blank">'.$match[1].'</a>';
                } else {
                    return 'What you want when validation fail!';
                }
            },
            $message
       );
```

Comment: I wonder if there are cases like `[link][/link]`. If yes you need `.*?`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Who knows? But it seems strange to have an empty link.

Comment: it replace properly, but dont forget why you need [link]! If you insert any user's url direct to html you, have XSS vulnerability. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS). Yum MUST filter input and escape output!

Comment: @Toto I really want a foreach loop, cause i want to run the link through a database and check if it's a virus or anything like that.